# FosUser Override Roles attribute

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.4

I would like to override the roles attribute of FOSUser in Symfony (3.4), because I want a user to have only one role.

By default, this attribute is an array, I want to override it to a string.
So I guess I have to override the default `__construct()` function? Because there is this line below in it :

```
$this->roles = array();
```

From what I found on Google, I maybe must to use an annotation like this one below on my user entity, can you confirm?

```
/*
 *  @AttributeOverrides({
 *      @AttributeOverride(name="roles",
 *          column=@Column(
 *              name     = "roles",
 *              type     = "string",
 *              length   = 30
 *  ))})
 */
```

Do I have the right idea? How could I override the constructor or get this working?

Comment: When I try to update my database with this annotation I got this error : The column type of attribute 'roles' on class 'UserBundle\Entity\User' could not be changed.

Comment: It seems like you're trying more of a band-aid fix on top of FOSUserBundle's entire structure.  I would instead build constraints into your application to not allow a user to have more than 1 role, rather than try to merely hack a database fix into it.

Answer (score 0):

Now, it's impossible, you can override only name, but you can't change type